# How to excute some code only for the first asp:button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

As I'm a newbie to asp.net I need to know whether there is anyway that I can execute some code only for the first button click for a asp:button in a web page.

Actually my requirement is that I need to enter checked values of a asp:check box list to database for the click event of a asp:button. I need to do some object creations only for the first time. Then I just need to add values to the database. How can I identify the first button click? If there is more efficient way than this?

Comment: store a value in session/cookie on first click and then check this value to determine if code was executed atleast once, also can you post some code  for object creating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Clicked"] == null)
        Session["Clicked"] = true;
    else {
        // We already ran this function once, so do other stuff from now on
        ...
        return;
    }

   // Code below this comment will be executed only on the 1st button click
   ...
}
```

Comment: but the thing is that I still need to add values to the database using that button click.Only thing is after the first button click I don't need to execute some code anymore. Is there anyway? Or any other better way?